# Test website by iterating every page and report which page produces error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Is there a plugin/extension/gem that iterates every page in a Rails app/website, to see if it renders properly, and returns a report with errors? Or am I over testing?

Comment: I've attempted something like this before and it's a LOT of work and highly problematic to the point where it would be simpler to write the tests manually. You can get somewhere by fetching the GET-based rake routes, but then you have to ensure the correct test data is in place, and automatically authenticate based on the url..the hoops go on and on.

Answer (score 0):

it seems what you are looking for is a smoke test gem, just google it and find whether that is something suite your need. And i find one here.

https://techblog.livingsocial.com/blog/2013/09/19/smokescreen-smoke-tests-for-ruby/